# How do I run a Kryonet server, only on one protocol?

Tags: java, udp, kryo

I'm currently planning to use the Java networking library, Kryonet, for my game. I'm going to use the UDP protocol, as it is faster than TCP. I like the Kryonet API, its very clean code, however it appears to only allow running of servers, on **both** TCP and UDP, when I only want a server running on UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should make the assumption that UDP is "faster" than TCP. TCP [SACK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018) and [NACK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4077) packets allow for faster retransmission requests than the older TCP sliding-window-only system, and the [Explicit Congestion Notification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification) enhancement makes it far easier for peers to communicate at a speed approaching the maximum the network can handle. (UDP would continue sending data oblivious to the congestion that leads to dropped packets.)

Test the bandwidth, latency, and packetloss between several intended peers and see which one performs better. I'll bet it comes out nearly the same.

Comment: For a real time game, similar to that of an FPS, you are saying it would run at relatively the same speed?

Comment: Ah, and would all clients support this, and how would I integrate this into Kryonet/networking code?

Comment: I presumed Kryonet supported servers running both TCP and UDP because their client bindings would also work on both environments. And yes, a FPS running both should run at about the same speed for either type of client connection. In fact, because each UDP packet can be lost or delivered out of order, the server may need to include more redundant data per packet to allow clients to "catch up" after losing some packets. The TCP stream would not need to send redundant data, because the client will get all of it, in order, though perhaps retransmissions may add 100ms occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Kryonet in fact does support connections with only one protocol, but this one protocol must be TCP. There are no UDP-only connections possible. TCP is mandatory.

Reason is, that kryonet uses TCP for all internal requests like server discovery, ping or the connection handshake. Doing this in UDP would require logic to deal with dropped or wrongly-ordered packages which kryonet just doesn't have implemented yet.